# How to implement adminLTE dashboard in my Django application?

Tags: django, dashboard, adminlte

How to implement adminLTE dashboard in my Django application?

I am developing a web application using django and i used admin-lte as a template.
In the dashboard part, I received as a result spaces without graph, and when I read the code, I did not understand where is the data used to design the graphs.
[adminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html)

[image: screenshot of my interface]
[image: screenshot of adminlte interface]

**PS :** everything works perfectly when i use [django-adminlte](https://pypi.org/project/django-adminlte-3/) as template, but i only have a problem with the dashboard.

Comment: There are django packages for this, so you could install one of these to get started; https://pypi.org/project/django-adminlte-3/

Comment: @markwalker_ This is what i used, my problem is the dashboard, i dont know how used it.